# I have a basic question of FOR loop list comprehension for particular pattern printing

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, list-comprehension, nested-loops

This is basic "for loop" pattern printing code as follows:

```py
for i in range (1,5):
    for j in range (i, 5):
        print(j , end='')
    print()
```

output:

```
1234
234
34
4
```

But I want the same as the above output using same logic using the List Comprehension.

for list Comprehension.

I tried :

```py
[print(j,end='') for i in range(1,5) for j in range(i,5)]
```

and output is:

```
1234234344
```

Comment: **don't use list comprehensions for side effects**

Comment: Nothing in you comprehension corresponds to the lone `print()` of the loop code, but as others have said -- it is a bad idea to use list comprehensions for side effects.

Comment: The really important thing to understand is that *list comprehensions **are not** for loops*. They are functional programming constructs designed to apply mapping/filtering operations over iterables to produce a list. They are *declarative constructs*. For-loops are basic control-flow statements, they *are imperative constructs*. Two different paradigms, and you shouldn't think of a list comprehension as "just a single-line for loop" at all

Comment: Thank you for your insight into the concept. I'll keep it in mind.@juanpa.arrivillaga,@John Coleman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can approach this by using a function instead :

```
def myfn(i):
    for j in range(i,5):
        print(j,end='')
    print()


[myfn(i) for i in range(1,5) ]
```

Comment: I said this in my answer but I'll say it here too: [don't use a list comprehension for side effects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5753614/4518341)

Comment: I just offered this answer if there is a reason behind asking the question.. otherwise Yes don't use the list comprehension approach! :)

Comment: @Tarekas, Thanks for the solution. It gave me one more approach.  But I was mainly looking for a list comprehension concept.

Answer (score 2):

[Don't use a list comprehension for side effects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5753614/4518341), use a plain for-loop instead, i.e. your original code.

But here's how you would do it, by using unpacking instead of a second loop:

```
[print(*range(i, 5), sep='') for i in range(1, 5)]
```

So you could do this instead:

```
for i in range(1, 5):
    print(*range(i, 5), sep='')
```

Comment: Thanks@wjandrea, Your answer is helpful. It cleared the confusion. There are no side effects.